# Outgoing bandwidth increased 4x for some unexplainable reason

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, cloudflare

I am running a game based on GWT+GAE, which contains many static image files (~25MB, mostly packed as JS GWT bundle). We have currently about 450 daily active users and about 30 registrations per day. This numbers are pretty constant since a couple of weeks. In max, they generated about **10GB** traffic per day. 
But last week something very odd happened: in the middle of the week, on the 19th Nov, the usage increased to over **40GB** and since then it stayed on this level.

I'm investigating it since a couple of days, but without any results so far - so I need your help and ideas, since the billing support is ignoring me.

Facts:

Date / DAU / Bandwidht

15.11 / 385/ 6.5 GB

16.11 / 585 / 9 GB

17.11 / 660 / 10 GB

18.11 / 451 / 12 GB

19.11 / 455 / 46 GB

20.11 / 438 / 42 GB

21.11 / 429 / 44 GB

There is a huge increase of outgoing bandwidth, but when we examine the charts from the dashboard, it's not clearly evident, why this happens (due to being new here no direct image post possible - sorry):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPfdV.jpg

On the 19th, we didn't deploy a new version or changed the configuration of the application.

We examined also the bandwidth correlated components (blob, mail, channel api)
but nothing has changed on that day.

As next, I downloaded the logs from all the days and summed up all response sizes, I got following result:

18.11: 3.9 GB

19.11: 4.2 GB

20.11: 3.8 GB

21.11: 4.1 GB

Beside the enormous discrepancy between the total sizes and the outgoing bandwdth, in the logs the sizes are quite constant also after the 19th. I have no idea at the moment where else should I look for the answer. Which services that aren't logged could lead to such behavoiur?

EDIT 28.11:
I deployed then the application on other app-id and did some 'unit' testing:

Clientside: Firebug measured ~20MB download (some images and JS)

Serverside: in the logs the response size of every GET of a ressource is 0 with status 200 (...3.cache.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 ...) and the total size of one game session according to logs is 715kB.

App Engine Dashboard: Outgoing bandwidth 0,11GB!

AppStats: none urlFetch, a couple of channel API send message - nothing spectacular.

Tried it with 3 browsers and accumulated 0.33GB outgoing bandwidth, although the logs say 2,5MB and according to the summed result of the clients about 65MB (what I expect).
Caching seems to work, since joining the second time, I only download 30kB according to Firebug and also the bandwidth counter in the dashboard doesn't go up in this situation.

Any help and ideas are greatly appreciated!

EDIT 10.12.2013:
As I wrote in the answer - the bug is fixed now. Additionally, I gave also CloudFlare a try and so we had yesterday a bandwidth usage of 3,5GB (yes, 1/12th)!
Since our app is a game and therefore consists of much static content, cloudfalre saves us 75% static file bandwidth and 66% of requests. The latency didn't change. It looks really promising :)

Comment: I would log a production issue, along with your evidence detailing the discrepancy. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue

Comment: Did you enable pagespeed?

Comment: No, we do not use PageSpeed since it doesn't fit our needs.

Comment: BTW. Tim, thanks for the production issue idea. Did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After submitting a ticket (had to buy silver suppport package), the problem was analyzed by google and it was indeed a bug in the app engine which caused discrepancies between real bandwidth usage from the logs and the billed values in the dashboard.
It's solved now.

Comment: Did they refund you for the silver support or compensate you in any ways for this issue which might have caused you to overpay for the outgoing bandwidth ?